# Can you plot time series falling into multiple categories in using R package Highcharter (or Highcharts) as you can in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, highcharts

From time to time you would like to plot time series that can have multiple labels, say, sex and ageGroup, for example. Let's say you would like to use colors to make a distinction between ageGroups and use dashed line for Female and solid line for Male. This is a piece of cake with ggplot2 i.e.

```
# Load the necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)

# Create synthetic data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  Time = rep(2000:2010, 2*3),
  Gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), each = 11*3),
  AgeGroup = rep(c("Young", "Middle-aged", "Elderly"), each = 11*2),
  Value = rnorm(66)
)

# Create a ggplot chart
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Time, y = Value, color = AgeGroup, linetype = Gender)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Young" = "red", "Middle-aged" = "blue", "Elderly" = "green")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Male" = "solid", "Female" = "dashed")) +
  labs(title = "Synthetic Data",
       x = "Time (year)",
       y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal()

# Print the chart
print(p)
```

And the plot looks like this:
[image: A plot]

However, in Highcharts you can only add a series, and you can change the line type for the series as well as color, but there will only one legend, since the Highcharts do not classify series belonging to a certain sex group or age group, am I wrong? If so, is there a way to achieve a similar plot with Highcharter too?